# report airflow dag run statistics after completion

Tags: report, hook, airflow

whilst the gantt chart is great, it's not exactly easy to summarize. I would like to report all its data over to something like influxdb (and present in grafana).

so the question is:

1) is there a general hook which is called after each and every completed dagrun?
2) how can grab the (eg gantt) data for each dagrun after it has completed (of even just how long the dag took to run)?

cheers!

Comment: If merely dag start-time and end-time are sufficient, then you can employ a simple `MySQLHook` / `MySQLOperator` (or whatever meta-db backend you are using) to query the [`dag_run`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/airflow/models/dagrun/index.html) table and publish the results

Comment: some useful links for airflow metrics export [link0](https://airflow.apache.org/metrics.html), [link1](https://pypi.org/project/airflow-exporter/), [link2](https://github.com/DanielMorales9/airflow-prometheus-pushgateway), [link3](https://github.com/astronomer/astronomer/blob/master/examples/airflow-monitoring/docker-compose.yml#L26), [link4](https://github.com/robinhood/airflow-prometheus-exporter)

Answer (score 0):

If your airflow is connected to Postgres, then you can add the airflow Postgres DB connection in grafana (https://grafana.com/docs/features/datasources/postgres/)